# Most efficient way of looping over 2 dimensional associative array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have a two dimensional associative array which contains a map of blocks that need to be drawn in a html5 canvas.

It currently takes around 28ms to complete it, which is too much (I'm running the code 60 times a second), I need to run though the matrix more efficienty somehow. This is my code:

```
for(var x=0; x<Object.keys(matrix).length; x++){ // Run through cols
    col = Object.keys(matrix)[x];
    for(var y=0; y<matrix[col].length; y++){ // Run though rows
        row = Object.keys(matrix[col])[y];
        if(matrix[col][row] != '0'){
            drawRect(col,row,blockSize,blockSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope it's inefficient and something can be corrected. How can you loop the total of a 2D array most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the double for loop to loop an entire 2-D array.  As with trying to speed up any code with a performance issue, the very first step is to figure out what is taking the most time and work on your optimizations in that element of the issue first.

The likely guess is that drawRect takes way more time than any of the issues in the loop, but if you want to speed up the rest of the code, you can do these things:

1. cache `Object.keys(matrix)` so it is not constantly recalculated
2. cache the stop value for each `for` loop so it is not re-computed every time through each loop
3. cache the column keys so it is not recalculated every time through the inner loop
4. cache the matrix column

That code would look like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(matrix);
for(var x = 0, lenX = keys.length; x < lenX; x++) { // Run through cols
    col = keys[x];
    var colKeys = Object.keys(matrix[col]);
    var matrixCol = matrix[col];
    for(var y = 0, lenY = matrix[col].length; y < lenY; y++) { // Run though rows
        row = colKeys[y];
        matrixCol[row] != '0'){
            drawRect(col,row,blockSize,blockSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about "matrix[col]" caching?

Comment: @kitgui.com - I added that one too.

Answer (score 1):

You should see first what takes the longest amount of time. My bet is that the drawRect function is the slowest of the bunch. Instead of drawing the rectangle try to print to the console (or write on the screen) and see how much time that takes. 
You can then calculate how much drawRect takes to perform 1 operation. I think that might be your problem, that drawRect takes too long to draw.

Comment: yes, drawRect() is the slowest part of the clode but I see no way to get around using it. As soon as I optimize the loop I'll see if there is a way to save each square position in a variable and draw all at once. Maybe it's possible, I don't know enough about html5 canvases

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for(var x=0, xlimit=Object.keys(matrix).length; x<xlimit; x++){ // Run through cols
    col = Object.keys(matrix)[x];
    for(var y=0, ylimit=matrix[col].length; y<ylimit; y++){ // Run though rows
        row = Object.keys(matrix[col])[y];
        if(matrix[col][row] != '0'){
            drawRect(col,row,blockSize,blockSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to reduce evaluations within the loop

```
var m = Object.keys(matrix), mc, x = 0, xlen = m.length, col, mcol, y, ylen, row;
for(;x < xlen; x++) {
  col = m[x];
  mc = matrix[col];
  for(y = 0, ylen = mc.length; y < ylen; y++) {
    row = mc[y];
    if(mc[row] != '0') {
      drawRect(col, row, blockSize, blockSize);
    }
  }
}
```

The main point is here to reduce the need for evaluations on object keys. Not sure how to reduce beyond that yet as I don't know what the functions are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some answers that suggested caching a lot of variables I made the drawing go from taking 30ms to 20ms.

However today I managed to get it to 1ms by removing Object.keys() and as I knew the range the keys would be in I changed x and lenX to preselect the range. Same with y and lenY. The load time almost doesn't scale at all with the size of the matrix. (I have tested a 100 times bigger matrix and it only starts to take 2ms).

```
minX = Math.floor(cameraPos.x/blockSize)*blockSize;
minY = Math.floor(cameraPos.y/blockSize)*blockSize;
maxX = minX+WIDTH+blockSize;
maxY = minY+HEIGHT+blockSize;
for(var col = minX; col < maxX; col+=blockSize) { // Run through cols
    for(var row = minY; row < maxY; row+=blockSize) { // Run though rows
        if(typeof matrix[col] !== "undefined" && typeof matrix[col][row] !== "undefined"){
            drawRect(xFix(col),yFix(row),blockSize,blockSize,blockColors[matrix[col][row]]);
        }
    }
}
```

Though the function is very fast it eventually starts scaling, to remove all scaling and in theory be able to make game maps ridiculously big I started to cache the map every time the camera scrolled a certain distance (now it's twice screen WIDTH but could be more). Since the area to cache is filtered with a similar function to this one it's done almost instantly.

```
var cached = [];
function cacheMap() {
    if(cached['pos'] === undefined || cameraPos.x < cached['pos']['x']-WIDTH || cameraPos.x > cached['pos']['x']+WIDTH || cameraPos.y < cached['pos']['y']-HEIGHT || cameraPos.y > cached['pos']['y']+HEIGHT) {
        cached['map'] = filterMatrix(map,cameraPos.x-WIDTH-blockSize*5,cameraPos.y-HEIGHT-blockSize*5,WIDTH*3+blockSize*10,HEIGHT*3+blockSize*10);
        cached['pos'] = {'x':cameraPos.x,'y':cameraPos.y};
        console.log('cached map');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Are you sure this is how you want to use StackOverflow, taking awarded reputation points away from others who helped you so you can vote for your own answer?  Especially when your answer includes things that we couldn't have possibly known about (like removing the `Object.keys()` call.  I understand how you wanted to share your final answer (nothing wrong with that), but somehow it seems backwards to take reputation points away from the answer that helped you the most by rescinding your prior vote for best answer.

Comment: Ok I marked you answer as it was the most helpfull. Still I should point out that my real problem was that I was looping the whole object, reducing the loop to a little area was what really made the difference.